# Where is to put another button like on the navigation bar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, interface-builder

I have a navigation bar on my `TableViewController` with two buttons on it  -- "Exit" and "+". I need to place third button to give the user the ability to change the account's password. What is the best place to put it? What is the best practice in such cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both buttons on same side? It's pretty common to have 2 buttons on any side if you place one on the other side

Comment: @Puran Can I place two buttons on the same side?

Comment: Use the answer below! self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[firstBarButton, secondBarButton];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple bar button items on a `UINavigationItem` using:

```
- (void)setLeftBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0); 
- (void)setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

So you have two UIBarbuttonItems inside of a `UIViewController`
`[self.navigationController.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:@[button1, button2]];`

If you are using a storyboard then you can only set one button on the left or right sides (I have no idea why, it's stupid) although you can but a regular `UIButton` in the title.

[image: Buttons on a Navigation Bar]

Comment: So the only way to have three bar button items on the navigation bar is to programmatically create it, right?

Comment: Yes, you have to at least create one programmatically. To answer thoroughly you could keep one in storyboard and use `self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` to retrieve one button and create the other in code but this gets confusing having UI code in two places.